# Xcode 8 print function just print the name of the object and its address in memory

Tags: swift3

With Xcode 8, when I do a `print("user : \(user)")`, in the console I only get `user : <Object_Class: 0x6080000b3fe0>`. Is there a way to have a more detailed print?

EDIT:

The class is `FIRUser` (Firebase).

```
/** @class FIRUser
    @brief Represents a user.
    @remarks This class is thread-safe.
 */
@interface FIRUser : NSObject <FIRUserInfo>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this class to conform to [CustomStringConvertible](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/protocol/CustomStringConvertible/) and implement the `description` property.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated the question. My class is `FIRUser`. I'm surprised google didn't implement this. But as it extends `NSObject`, shouldn't I get the description of `NSObject`?

Comment: No I'm using Swift, that's what I get from the header file.

Comment: Right, I see now. Well, my answer stands. The description of NSObject is its address. You need to put an extension on this puppy and do what I said to do.